# How can I reference all attributes of the user model to a different model?

Tags: django-models

I have a complain model having different fields like email,first_name,last_name etc and I want to reference them from user model but I didn't know how to do this .

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class complain(models.Model):
First_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
Last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
Roll_no=models.CharField(max_length=30)
Email_address=models.EmailField(max_length = 100,verbose_name='email address',blank=False,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let the class complain extends from user which provided by django auth part .

Comment: How to extend it ?

Answer (score 0):

**I want to reference them from user model.**
Then you can use a Foreign key Here.

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class complain(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Roll_no=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: By only referencing user can I refer all the fields like First_name, Last_name, Email of the user model into complain model.

Comment: Yes, Let's have a `complain` object `o`. Then you can refer to `first_name` using `o.user.first_name`. There is a lot of documentation on this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: Kindly elaborate sir what you are saying. I am very new to Django.

Comment: I believe you are tracking the user who gave a complaint. So While Creating a Complain object, you can specify the user directly instead of giving first_name, last_name, etc. `Complain.objects.create(user=request.user, roll_no="abc", ...)`. I hope you understand what is `request.user`.

Comment: No I am using a complain form based on my complain model and from there I want to save my complain for different users that are registered. I want to get their registration details like username,First_name,Last_name,email and use it in my complain form.

Comment: To keep it simple, Every user has their registration details. Now instead of saving those details again, save the user itself. From this, you can still access the registration details. By this data will be consistent with no redundancy.